# Can I use German Rail Luggage Service to send luggage from Frankfurt Main Airport to Airbnb in Chemnitz?

Tags: trains, luggage, germany, deutsche-bahn

Note, posted as an answer:
*Hermes does no longer transfer luggage from the airport or to the airport. They will only pick up or deliver to hotel or a private address.*

I want to use [Bahn Gepaeckservice](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/buchung/gepaeck/db-gepaeckservice.shtml?dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D092_KIN0051_DEFAULT-ANSW-DB_LZ01) to send my luggage from Frankfurt Main Airport to an Airbnb in Chemnitz. The Airbnb is a private apartment. I'm a tourist and do not live in Germany. The Bahn's web page mentions:

> Selbstverständlich übernimmt die Gepäckaufbewahrung auch bei Ihrer Rückreise den Gepäckversand nach Hause.

Which means the Bahn (or the airport's luggage service) will send the luggage from the airport to the persons home ("nach Hause") — which I assume must be in Germany.

I already asked on [bahn.de](https://community.bahn.de/questions/1220624-flughafen-gepaeckservice-gepaeck-frankfurt-flughafen-hotel) but the answer does not clearly state that tourists can use the service and they directed me to the airport's left-luggage-office (although it seems the Bahn is offering this service).

1. Can a tourist (non resident) use this service to send luggage to an Airbnb address?
   I'm worried that the Bahn wants to see an ID document which shows a permanent address in Germany.
2. If I can use the service, where do I go to at the airport — the Bahn or the left-luggage-office?
3. Alternatively, can I send my heavy luggage from Frankfurt airport to Chemnitz some other way?

Comment: I haven't used the service before, but what I can tell from the pages you linked: If you can use the service, you drop your luggage at the left-luggage-office, where it will be picked up. However, online booking is only possible home to airport or home to airport and back. Maybe phone booking is different. The service is a cooperation with Hermes, and you can book luggage transport with Hermes directly, check https://www.myhermes.de/de/landingpages/gepaeckservice.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) According to the website (https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/buchung/gepaeck/db-gepaeckservice.shtml?dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D092_KIN0051_DEFAULT-ANSW-DB_LZ01) I do not see any problem if you are not a german citizen.

2) In Frankfurt? Frankfurt/M.: Terminal 1, Halle B, Ankunft ("Arrival")

3) Well should work with the Bahn. I had a look at their website where you enter all the data (https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/kuriergepaeckbuchen/kuriergepaeck_start.post?scope=standalone#stay) and for you "Rückfahrt" (return journey) and "Hinfahrt" (outward journey) would be the other way around as you go from somewhere to germany and not from germany to somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I used the Bahn Gepaeckservice at Frankfurt airport a couple of days ago. I landed at the airport and had my luggage sent to my hotel without a prior booking. This is what I did.

1. Go to terminal 1.
2. Go to the Germany railways office near the regional trains.
3. Give them the address of the hotel (and optionally a phone number).
4. Pay Eur 17.5 per bag and get a Auftragsnummer (order number).
5. Go to the luggage storage office (Gepaeck Aufbewahrung). Give them the Auftragsnummer together with the luggage.
6. Go to [Hermes Tracking](https://www.myhermes.de/wps/portal/paket/Home/privatkunden/sendungsverfolgung) and enter the Auftragsnummer to track the delivery.
7. Delivery took 5 days (I arrived on a Sunday). Might be quicker during the week.

Answer (score 3):

Hermes does no longer transfer luggage from the airport or to the airport. They will only pick up or deliver to hotel or a private address.