# Sending unaccompanied bag from one German City to Another by Train

Tags: trains, luggage, germany

I will fly in internationally to Frankfurt and then to Stuttgart via Deutsche Bahn.

Then after a few days in Stuttgart I have to fly from Stuttgart to Berlin for a short business meeting and then to Munich. I will have my travel bags (say 15 to 18 kilos not too big) with me at Stuttgart but they don't need to do the trip to Berlin. I can travel light and then say fly to Munich where I would want my travel bag.

Is there a way (say) via Deutsche Bahn (or otherwise) where I could drop off my bigger bag at Stuttgart railway station and have them move it to Munich on a train and I can later (say the next day or in 2 days) pick it up at Munich?

Basically it allows me to not drag my heavy bag when not needed and also fly a cabin bags only flight leg (much cheaper).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Similar, but old: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82755/can-i-use-german-rail-luggage-service-to-send-luggage-from-frankfurt-main-airpor

Answer (score 3):

The Germany Trains (bahn.de) are offering this service but only in conjunction with a train ticket. You could probably buy dummy ticket: cheapest for Stuttgart to Munich would be around 13 Euros if you book in advance by a week or so. See https://www.bahn.de/angebot/zusatzticket/gepaeck (sorry, it's in German only)

There are also private carriers that offer this. DHL seems to be the cheapest and they are  ubiquitous in Germany. They used to have a special offer for this, but this may have expired at the beginning of the year. https://www.dhl.de/en/privatkunden/pakete-versenden/deutschlandweit-versenden/reisegepaeck.html

Other options would be UPS or Hermes (which the Bahn uses) and a few more. To get a quote, you need to poke in your exact details (dimensions, postal codes, weight).

I would probably choose a carrier that has drop off and pick up points, close to your hotels. That makes dropping and retrieving the bag easier and the pick point can hold it for a day or two, depending on how long you are staying in Berlin.

Comment: One could probably ship to the hotel directly. Check with the hotel beforehand, though.

Comment: Depends on the hotel. I once had a hotel in London trying to charge me 1£/hour for bag storage. Yikes.

Comment: in the present case if I correctly understand OP's plans, the bags should arrive after they have checked in, so it shouldn't be an issue. Still, check with the hotel, especially regarding how they should be addressed so they accept them and manage to deliver them to you (timely!).